# Wait for previous Rx Observable to Finish

Tags: android, rx-java

Hi I'm using RxJava for my disk storage get and set operations. Basically I have a method like this:

```
public Observable<String> getStorageItem(String id, String type) {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
        // Run db operations to get storage item.
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's possible this method `getStorageItem(...)` gets subscribed to multiple times in a row. And the DB operations within the observable cannot run concurrently. What's my best option here? Should I manually create some sort've queue? Or does RxJava have some kind of tool that allows me to block the operation until a previous one is complete?

Comment: Actually I think I can just solve this with a synchronized lock within all of my Db operations. Silly me. But would love to hear if anyone else has any opinions on this.

Comment: You could take a look and see if `flatMap(Func1, int)` fits your needs (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1,%20int))

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `subscribeOn` with a single-threaded scheduler created from an `ExecutorService` to make sure there's only one DB operation in progress:

```
ExecutorService exec = Schedulers.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Scheduler s = Schedulers.from(exec);

public Observable<String> getStorageItem(String id, String type) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        // Do DB operations 
    });
}

getStorageItem("1", "2").subscribeOn(s).subscribe(...);
getStorageItem("2", "4").subscribeOn(s).subscribe(...);
getStorageItem("3", "6").subscribeOn(s).subscribe(...);
```

But note that by moving the computation off the caller's thread, it may execute any time. If you need to wait for it individually (because the getStorageItem is already called on some thread), you can apply `toBlocking()` after `subscribeOn`.